# How can I print a PDF-file together with all the linked files in it?

Tags: pdf, printing

I'm trying to print a PDF-File wich contains some links to other PDF-Files.
I could not find a solution to print the additional linked files together with the main PDF-File.

example: 
I have a PDF-File, with normal text but also links to other files. 
And I want to print the main file together with te linked Files with a local printer in my Room.

kind regards,
Viman4s

Comment: is it general question or relates to programming? please, elaborate and provide some code snippets which you tried so far. But it really looks like an off-topic for stackoverflow for now.

Comment: I haven't tryed to code anything yet. Im just searching for some possible solutions...

Comment: Viman4s, try googling then. This kind of question is counted to be off-topic on StackOverflow. Try using http://superuser.com/

Comment: I googled it already. ok i'll try it out on SuperUser... have you got any idea?